# JFrame defined in one class, JComponent extended in another

Tags: java, class, jcomponent

Relatively new to Java, coding for a school project.

I'm using JFrame and JComponent, drawing patterns and strings and all that fun stuff.

Currently, I have a class written that extends JComponent. This is the class where I am defining most of my shapes. The issue is that I initialized my Jframe 
(Code: JFrame myFrame = new JFrame() ) in the main of one class, but I need to access myFrame.getWidth() in the JComponent class that I'm working in.

How can I access variables getWidth() and getHeight() in "public class MyJComponent extends JComponent" , when I defined myFrame in 'public class Lab2' ??

Edit for code:

```
public class Lab2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello Java");

    JFrame myFrame = new JFrame();

    myFrame.setSize(500, 500);
    myFrame.setTitle("Color Test");
    myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    MyJComponent myComponent = new MyJComponent(500, 500);
    myFrame.add(myComponent);
    myFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white); //sets background color.

    myFrame.setVisible(true);   // setVisible() *after* add() is the norm



    //Deciding geometry of hidden shape. paintComponent is called once per run, this is called afterwards.

}

}
```

/**/

```
public class MyJComponent extends JComponent {

int[] circleX;
int[] circleY;
int[] circleR;
final int MIN_RADIUS = 5;
final int MAX_RADIUS = 15;
final int MIN_SEPARATION = 1;
final int MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5000;
final int MAX_CIRCLES = 1000;
Random rand;
int initialWidth;
int initialHeight;
int numCircles;   // actual number of circles drawn



// are circles at index i and index j separated by *<= tolerance* pixels?

boolean twoCirclesOverlap(int i, int j, int tolerance) {
    double distanceBetweenCenters =
            Math.sqrt((circleX[i] - circleX[j]) * (circleX[i] - circleX[j]) +
                    (circleY[i] - circleY[j]) * (circleY[i] - circleY[j]));
    return (distanceBetweenCenters <= (circleR[i] + circleR[j] + tolerance));
}

// are any existing circles separated from the proposed one at index i by *<= tolerance* pixels?

boolean anyCirclesOverlap(int i, int tolerance) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (twoCirclesOverlap(i, j, tolerance)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// attempt to randomly place the largest-possible circle that does not overlap any existing one

boolean tryToPlaceCircle(int i) {

    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_ATTEMPTS; j++) {

        // pick a random position, set initial radius to minimum

        circleX[i] = rand.nextInt(initialWidth);
        circleY[i] = rand.nextInt(initialHeight);
        circleR[i] = MIN_RADIUS;

        // grow circle until it touches another or reaches max size

        while (!anyCirclesOverlap(i, MIN_SEPARATION) && circleR[i] < MAX_RADIUS)
            circleR[i]++;

        // it was touching from the start -- must try again

        if (circleR[i] == MIN_RADIUS) {
            continue;
        }

        // grew to max size -- well done

        else if (circleR[i] == MAX_RADIUS) {
            return true;
        }

        // grew some, but then touched

        else {
            circleR[i]--;   // retract to the step before touch
            return true;
        }
    }

    // all attempts failed

    return false;
}

MyJComponent(int width, int height) {

    circleX = new int[MAX_CIRCLES];
    circleY = new int[MAX_CIRCLES];
    circleR = new int[MAX_CIRCLES];

    initialWidth = width;
    initialHeight = height;

    rand = new Random();

    numCircles = 0;
    while (numCircles < MAX_CIRCLES && tryToPlaceCircle(numCircles)) {
        numCircles++;
    }
}

//Override paintComponent
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    for (int i = 0; i < numCircles; i++) {
        g.drawOval(circleX[i] - circleR[i], circleY[i] - circleR[i], 2 * circleR[i], 2 * circleR[i]);
    }
}

//Shape decision
public void shapeDecision() {
    double randomShapeDecider = Math.random();
    if (randomShapeDecider > .50) {
        //shape is circle, define it's properties
        hiddenCircleDiameter = myFrame.getWidth();

    }
    else {
        //shape is rectangle
        hiddenRectangleWidth = myFrame.getWidth();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: done, I just added my code